# Extent for Robinson projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, wms, qgis-server, proj4js

I'm trying to use a QGIS WMS layer and show it on a Robinson projection but can't get it working.

The ol-debug shows a "transform should be defined" error, I think it's because of a wrong projection extent.

[Official epsg.io documentation for ESRI:54030](http://epsg.io/54030) doesn't show a bound, so also [OL projection example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html) doesn't work as [bbox is empty](https://epsg.io/?format=json&q=54030).

Here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/fcmakua6/) with my attempts showing successful use of the WMS layer with EPSG::4326 and error with ESRI:54030 projection.

Comment: No idea if your world extent is a problem. In Esri software, the min/max extents for Esri:54030 are (x,y order): -16986823.31, -8615716.7828563 and 16986823.31, 8615716.7828563. Your center is 151195.612863, 4441146.976346.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to add WMS layer in Robinson projection, because proj4js doesn't support this kind of projection, see [#191](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/191).

Comment: ok, so to add support for Robinson to proj4js there has to be added a projection js file to https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/tree/master/lib/projections right?

Comment: seems quite complex Robinson implementation of proj.4 but porting this to proj4s would be a way: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218079/extent-for-robinson-projection